# How to assign a shortcut to "Open Image in New Tab" in Safari?

Tags: keyboard, safari, mojave, shortcut, shortcut-menu

I can see the option to `Open Image in New Tab` in the context menu whenever I right click on any image in Safari.

[image: Context Menu option: <code>Open Image in New Tab</code>]

I tried to assign an App Shortcut in my MacOS by:

1. Going to System `Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`
2. Clicking on the `+` icon
3. Selecting

   - Application: **Safari**
   - Menu Title: Open Image in New
     Tab
   - Keyboard Shortcut: `⌘B`

I tried assigning some other keyboard shortcuts too in place of `⌘B` but it just does not seem to work in **Safari**. Is there any solution?

Comment: **Open Image in New Tab** is a _context menu command_, not a **Safari** _menu bar command_, and why you cannot assign it a _keyboard shortcut_ in the manner in which you tried. Only an app's _menu bar command_ can be assigned a _keyboard shortcut_ in that manner. I do not know of a way to add a _keyboard shortcut_ to a _command_ that is only a _context menu command_. You can however *⌘-click** an image to open it in a new tab.

Comment: @user3439894 I wanted to know if there is a shortcut for `Open Image in New Tab` in the context menu which works even if the image is not a link unlike `⌘-click` which only works if it is a link.